# Can the small voltage output from a dc hobby motor (used as a generator) be amplified to light an led or flashlight bulb?

Tags: voltage

I built a small windmill and connected it to a small dc hobby motor, using the motor as a generator. I want to light a small led or flashlight bulb. Is there some kind of simple capacitor/diode/resistor combo I can use to boost the voltage enough to.do this?

Comment: You could always try a joule thief circuit. http://rimstar.org/sdenergy/joule_thief.htm

Comment: How much voltage and current is your generator producing?

Comment: Pick the motor with the lowest Kv (RPM/Volt) you can find, because that gives you the highest volt/RPM as a generator. If you can't find/buy what you need, the simplest (theoretical) way is to rewind a motor with more turns of wire, (thinner wire, to fit the available space) if you're up to performing such surgery.

Comment: Be aware (you may be) that you can step up one or other of voltage OR current but you cannot "step up" energy or power. If the input power is not enough to supply the load requirement, adjusting voltage will not help. | That said, a small motor will usually provide enough power and you need to change the voltage. Small motors that run on DC and that have "brushes" make DC output when used as a generator. Motors without brushes such as 5V or 12V fan motors, make AC voltage when used as an alternator BUT this is usually blocked by internal electronics which must be bypassed for them  to be ...

Comment: ... used as an alternator. A motor with DC output can use a "Joule thief" circuit but these are usually super horrible circuits with low efficiency. Often slightly better is to use the electronics from a cheap single cell "lawn light" which droves an LED from one NiCd or NimH cell. (A very few use LiFePO4 cells which are less suitable in this application). There are other alternatives but comment on whether this meets your needs.

Comment: Low voltage 'hobby' motors are not a good choice unless geared up to get higher rpm. As Brian Drummond says, use a motor with the lowest Kv you can get (which also means the motor designed to run on the highest voltage) as this will produce the highest voltage at low rpm. Something like this:- http://www.ebay.com/itm/1PCS-New-RF370-10800-Motor-DC6-24V-1200RPM-5000RPM-High-Torque-Motor-/141714380360?hash=item20fed5d648:g:cK8AAOSwT6pVnm6W

Answer (score 2):

Be aware (you may be) that you can step up one or other of voltage OR current but you cannot "step up" energy or power. If the input power is not enough to supply the load requirement, adjusting voltage will not help.

That said, a small motor will usually provide enough power and you usually need to change the voltage.

Small motors that run on DC and that have "brushes" make DC output when used as a generator.

Motors without brushes such as 5V or 12V fan motors, make AC voltage when used as an alternator BUT this is usually blocked by internal electronics which must be bypassed for them to be used as an alternator.

A motor with DC output can use a "Joule thief" circuit as mentioned by Jim Dearden - but these are usually super horrible circuits with low efficiency. Often slightly better is to use the electronics from a cheap single cell "lawn light" which droves an LED from one NiCd or NimH cell. (A very few use LiFePO4 cells which are less suitable in this application). There are other alternatives but comment on whether this meets your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't about voltage but about power. See the rating of your lightbulb, your motor and your windmill. If the lightbulb needs more power than any of the other components can deliver, it won't work.

Flashlight bulbs come in various ratings from 0.5W to 3W, at 1.5V to 6V. See what you have. Small DC motors as used in model trains etc usually have 2..5W, at 1..6V. So the problem is most likely your windmill.

$$P = 0.5 \cdot c_p \cdot \rho \cdot  A \cdot v^3$$

Rule of thumb for efficiency of small windmills:
$$c_p \approx 0.1$$

Air density at sea level:
$$\rho \approx 1.2\frac{kg}{m^3}$$

Put in the area touched by the rotor A=pi*(rotor radius)² and the wind speed v. For a small windmill with a 30cm radius rotor, you get A=0.3m².

$$P = 0.5 \cdot 0.1 \cdot 1.2\frac{kg}{m^3} \cdot 0.3m^2 \cdot v^3 = 0.018\frac{kg}{m} \cdot v^3 $$

What's your wind speed? At a not too windy day in fall, it's usually 2m/s. Your power can be

$$P = 0.018\frac{kg}{m} \cdot (2\frac{m}{s})^3 = 0.15W$$

That's not much. Look for a storm. If you have 20m/s instead of 2m/s, power output will be 1000 times more.

Comment: Equations would be much more valuable with the terms defined.

Comment: Cp is a term where all efficiency goes in. Small handmade windmills without much thought in them have roughly 10%, commercial ones for 100m towers may reach 60%. Rho is air density. P, A and v are explained.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, it's all matter of power and efficiency. The wind power is converted to electric power with some efficiency, then voltage is boosted with some other efficiency, whatever remains- will be used for light. So you will have to optimize efficiency. Generator is efficient on certain speed, boost converter is efficient on certain boost ratio and current. I can't say more without more details.

Answer (score 0):

Very bright LEDs flashlights only need a few Watts at some multiple of 3V if in series. Conversion is achievable if the generator has enough power.

## Start by measuring the motor power and maximize the windpower speed. Since RPM is proportion to voltage and torque is proportional to current you need both to get power.

- Therefore measure the open circuit voltage variations then find a power resistor that will only reduce the voltage 20 to 30 % which may be close to the Maximum Power Point (MPP) or use a transistor with bias and trimpot with a 50~100mV current shunt to measure voltage and current and determine what is the V,I when open circuit voltage is reduced by 20 to 30 %.

  - Like Solar Panels this will tell us how you can best achieve the best results.

Understand that if the motor and fan has excessive friction your efficiency will be low and you can never achieve the power rating of the motor unless your wind power turbine has the torque and RPM to drive this power.

## You cannot do both at the same time.

- This "impedance ratio" design is the job of all "power Conversion systems" in order to either *maximize efficiency and "load regulation" * with a 10~50x higher impedance load or *maximize output power*  with a perfectly matched impedance load, depending on what is more *important*. e.g. a transmission is an impedance convertor for Torque and RPM.

Believe it or not a Nuclear reactor is only 50% efficient. ( according to family friend who is a Sr. Nuclear Engineer) This goes into waste heat and steam from the heat exchangers and constant power source supply running at 100% with **low demand* due to politicians and hobbyists making wind and solar power experiments.  ( just kidding guys.. almost)

If the source is very low impedance then a step-up converter will work, given sufficient windpower. If the generator is high impedance, high voltage, then a step-down converter will work better.

The one our team designed in 1975 was a Sevonious/Darrius 20m vertical axis with
only a 5 MPH start speed that could start charging pile batteries  to charge our floating weather station in the Arctic. Then wing flaps for over speed after 1kW were safety governors then speed brakes.  But in the early 90's I have seen little tri-blade (6") props from model airplanes used at very high RPM generate high voltage stepped down to lower voltage to deliver maximum power. So the blade design is crucial for the wind stream available. Which comes to matching source /load impedances.  e.g A roof top whirlybird Vent can easily power a few Watts of LEDs but not a tiny little fan blade.

Answer (score 0):

Having done this (20 years ago in school) another approach is to gear up the motor (pulleys and a belt drive work well if you can get the tension, Lego or Meccano are other options).  This will get your voltage up, which is almost certainly what you need to do.  Most home-made windmills are very slow compared to most motors' no-load speeds.

Comment: The easiest way to trade torque for speed is mounting more blades. See the difference between 60-blade "western-style" rotors and today's 3-blade rotors.